# Swap certain subset of column data

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to swap a subset of the data in two columns, but all the methods that I have found on SO give a full swap, or also swap the column names. This is what I would like:

```
df = 
     a     b     c
0    1     2     3 
1    1     2     3
2    1     2     3
3    1     2     3
```

Then I create a random mask:

```
mask = np.random.choice([False, True], len(df), p=[0.5, 0.5])
```

Applying the mask and the swap, I want the result to look like this if I swap `df[mask]['a']` and `df[mask]['b']`:

```
df = 
     a     b     c
0    1     2     3 
1    2     1     3
2    1     2     3
3    2     1     3
```

What is the best way to achieve this result? I am using `pandas` 0.18.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one line:

```
mask = np.random.choice([False, True], len(df), p=[0.5, 0.5])

df.loc[mask, ['a', 'b']] = df.loc[mask, ['b', 'a']].values
```

Comment: This definitely seems like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = np.random.choice([False, True], len(df), p=[0.5, 0.5])

df[['b', 'a']] = np.where(mask[:, None], df[['b', 'a']], df[['a', 'b']])
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  1  3
2  2  1  3
3  2  1  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1]*4, "b":[2]*4})
mask = np.random.choice([False, True], len(df), p=[0.5, 0.5])
df["a_bk"] = df["a"].copy()
df["a"] = np.where(mask, df["b"], df["a"])
df["b"] =  np.where(mask, df["a"], df["b"])
del df["a_bk"]
```